# React native form design

Tags: react-native

I want to create in form in react native which has material input text.
same like shown here https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

Here is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from "react- 
      native";

     export default class App extends Component<Props> {
         render() {
            return <TextInput style={styles.abcd} placeholder="Enter name" />;
        }
    }

     const styles = StyleSheet.create({
       abcd: {
              borderBottomWidth: 0.25,
              marginVertical: 2,
              paddingHorizontal: 10
         }
       });
```

Here, I have used a placeholder, but if you see the form in the given link, then it's not placeholder. Also, the text is moving in an upward direction, when we are clicking on the field. The same thing I want to achieve here.
I don't want to use any libraries like textField or any other library.

Answer (score 0):

The `placeholder` prop on TextInput components has the place-holding text disappear upon the start of input. To achieve what you want to do, you can overlay a Text component over your TextInput component and map its style to a state variable. Upon focus, change the Text component's styling accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, 
There are two things
 1. React-Native material input box is only available in Android by default.
 2. On iOS, (iPhone or iPad) you will see normal InputBox

To see the material input box on iOS devices, you have to do lots of coding. The best solution is to integrate third-party libraries like [react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper)

Please refer a working example over here with `react-native-paper` library

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/example/src/TextInputExample.js